# Date value did not match format specified [YYYY-MM-DD] Error in Psycopg2 while COPY

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

i have an issue while copying a csv file from s3 to redshift, i'm getting error with the format of a specific column

This is the create table statement

```
"create table public.prueba_06_2020 (fecha DATE , hora TIMESTAMP , cantidad BIGINT , codrpta VARCHAR(165), respuesta VARCHAR(165), codtrn VARCHAR(165), codnuevo VARCHAR(165), descripcion_transaccion VARCHAR(165), descripcion_respuesta VARCHAR(165), respnueva VARCHAR(165));"
```

and this is the copy statement

```
"copy public.prueba_06_2020 from 's3://plink-redshift-dev/tiempo_real_app/Transaccion Real.csv' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/XXXXXXXXXx' csv dateformat as 'YYYY-MM-DD';"
```

i also try the same code without dateformat. and if i look at the column in the csv it's like this

```
df.fecha.unique()
Out[25]: array(['2020-06-03'], dtype=object)
```

the stl_load_error table is throwing this error

```
"Invalid Date Format - length must be 10 or more   "  
---or in case i use dateformat--- 
"Date value did not match format specified [YYYY-MM-DD] "
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are there any empty values in the date column in the CSV file?

Comment: no, as you can see in the line df.fecha.unique() the column just have 1 value 2020-06-03

Comment: I don't have any good answer, except that I wonder if Pandas is ignoring something that redshift is not ignoring. Can you manually inspect the CSV file, and see if there are any interesting lines? Is the first row a header? Are there any completely blank lines?

Comment: @jufegome the `stl_load_errors` gives you the column `raw_field_value` - does it also indicate `2020-06-03`. Can you maybe paste the whole `stl_load_errors` row?

Comment: I look at the csv file and it had the original headers so i change it to no headers,the stl_load_error table still gives me the same error and there is something else i dont understand. 
this is the raw_value '2020-06-04 00:00:00' but  mi actual value is '2020-06-04'